# Removing values in lists by user input (Python)

Tags: python, list, function

First time poster and I am very new to programming in general, (so please go easy on me) although I have worked in the IT industry as a help desk technician and field engineer.

I am in my first year at university and and have been asked to add a section on to a program to allow the user to remove entries that they have inputted into a list.

This is my code.

```
values = []
def programMenu():
    print('This program will accept values until 0 is entered.')
    choice = continueChoice()
    if choice == 'Y':
        ages = collectValues()
        print('There are ', len(values),' in the data set.')
        print('The values are as follows:', end ='')
        print(values)
        
        
    else:
        return
def continueChoice():
    print('Would you like to continue(Y/N):', end ='')
    choice = str(input()).upper()
    print(choice)
    while choice != 'Y' and choice != 'N':
        print('Invalid option. Would you like to continue(Y/N):', end ='')
        choice = str(input()).upper()
    return choice

def collectValues():
    values = []
    while True:
        print ('Please enter each value:', end ="")
        valValue = (int(input()))
        if (valValue ==0):
            break
        values.append(valValue)
        
    return values
    
        
def removeValues():
    print(values)
    print('Would you like to delete any entries?')
    reage = str(input()).upper()
    while reage == 'Y':
        print('Which ages would you like to remove')
        delVal = (int(input()))
        values.remove(delVal)
        
    else:
        programMenu()

        
programMenu()
removeValues()
```

I have been trying to solve this for two days but I am getting an error "ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list"
I have tried writing the removeValues code at the end of the operation to add values, I have tried to move the values = [] call around etc and have had no luck.

I checked  the removeValues definition was actually taking the input by editing to get the program to print the value the user entered that they wished to be removed and that worked.

Any help is appreciated, I've only been coding a few months and I have emailed my lecturer but giving what's happening in the world at the moment the university are understaffed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the main issue is that if delVal is 0, the program will attempt to remove 0 from the values list prior to stopping, which is probably where your error comes from. I also think having "values = []" inside the collectValues function will reset your "values" list to empty every time the function is called.

Comment: You are messing up function scope and global scope.`values` is not being addressed correctly inside your functions. Also, you need to check if a value is present in the list before attempting to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before deleting the value from the list you need to add a if condition to check if value is present in the list or not for example:

```
if delVal in values:
    values.remove(delVal)
else:
    print('Value Not Found in the list')
```

and your while loop is in infinite loop as value of reage = 'Y' and you are not changing it inside the loop to stop.

you can use if statement instead of while.

```
def removeValues():
    print(values)
    print('Would you like to delete any entries?')
    reage = str(input()).upper()
    # if reage == 'Y'
    if reage == 'Y':
        print('Which ages would you like to remove')
        delVal = (int(input()))
        # check if delVal is present in the list or not
        if delVal in values:
            values.remove(delVal)
            print('Deleted Age : '+ str(delVal))
            print(values)
        # if not then print the msg.
        else:
            print(str(delVal)+' Not Found in the list: ',str(values))
            # you can uncomment the below code to again call removeValues function to ask for correct value to delete
            #removeValues()
    # if reage is not equal to 'Y' then it calls the programMenu again.
    else:
        programMenu()
```

Comment: Brilliant! This worked and I see where I went wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to remove it because you are initializing the values in collectValues function each time. So the list is storing any value - just comment on this line and should work. Anyway, you also need to have exit criteria for each other functions.

```
values = []
def programMenu():
    print('This program will accept values until 0 is entered.')
    choice = continueChoice()
    if choice == 'Y':
        ages = collectValues()
        print('There are ', len(values),' in the data set.')
        print('The values are as follows:', end ='')
        print(values)
        
        
    else:
        return
def continueChoice():
    print('Would you like to continue(Y/N):', end ='')
    choice = str(input()).upper()
    print(choice)
    while choice != 'Y' and choice != 'N':
        print('Invalid option. Would you like to continue(Y/N):', end ='')
        choice = str(input()).upper()
    return choice

def collectValues():
    #values = []
    while True:
        print ('Please enter each value:', end ="")
        valValue = (int(input()))
        if (valValue ==0):
            break
        values.append(valValue)
        
    return values
    
        
def removeValues():
    print(values)
    print('Would you like to delete any entries?')
    reage = str(input()).upper()
    while reage == 'Y':
        print('Which ages would you like to remove')
        delVal = (int(input()))
        values.remove(delVal)
        
    else:
        programMenu()

        
programMenu()
removeValues()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that can be improved but I will try to keep the interface more or less the same.

The biggest issue is that functions in python have their own scope. That is, when you create a variable or list in a function, it is not shared in other functions.

What you need to do instead, (i think you had the right idea), is to create the list outside the functions and pass a reference to it as a parameter to each function:

```
    values = []
    
    
    def programMenu(values):
        print('This program will accept values until 0 is entered.')
        choice = continueChoice()
        if choice == 'Y':
            temp = collectValues()
            values += temp          # Append new values elementwise
            print('There are ', len(values), ' in the data set.')
            print('The values are as follows:', end='')
            print(values)
        else:
            return

    def removeValues(values):
        print(values)
        print('Would you like to delete any entries? (Y to continue)')
        while str(input()).upper() == 'Y':
            print('Which ages would you like to remove')
            delVal = (int(input()))
            values.remove(delVal)
            print('Would you like to delete any entries? (pressY to continue)')
        else:
            programMenu(values)

    programMenu(values)
    removeValues(values)
```

The above functions need a reference to the initial list in order to manipulate it.  Finally, a small change, in the `removeValues()` function, i moved the input in the while loop so that the question persists.

```
    def collectValues():
        values = []     # Not the same "values" list (not passed from reference)
        while True:
            print ('Please enter each value:', end="")
            valValue = (int(input()))
            if (valValue ==0):
                break
            values.append(valValue)
    
        return values
```

If you have noticed, the `collectValues()` function does not need a reference since it only gets new values and later adds them to the `values` list. Also, by creating a new list in `collectValues()`, the other list is not affected ( it is entirely independent).